# Getting xyz co-ordinates from a .map file (CCP4 format) in VMD

Tags: xray-crystallography, ccp4

I have a .map file which contains x-ray crystallography data of a bacteriophage. The format of the file is CCP4. I can open the file using VMD. However, I am unable to get the xyz co-ordinates. It shows the following error when I click on the option of saving data in xyz format:

`No timesteps selected; trajectory file will not be written.'

It is a big file of 64MB.

The file I am referring to may be downloaded at:
ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/emdb/structures/EMD-1086/map/emd_1086.map.gz

Can't we save xyz co-ordinates for CCP4 files? Or is it possible to extract any other form of data?

I am new to VMD and these formats.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's an electron density map. What xyz coordinates do you want to extract?

Answer (score 2):

Just Download and Install: [CCP4: Software for Macromolecular Crystallography](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/)

Comment: CCP4 is a suite of 200+ programs, just installing it won't solve any problem.